# last time vs the last time

Tags: grammar

I was wondering what the difference between *the last time* and *last time* is. In the following two sentences, why does the first sentence use *the last time*? Can I change it to *last time*?

> Are you sending me on a fool's errand again? *The last time* you sent me to get tickets, the play wasn't even on.

> *Last time* we talked about the three forms of water.

Does *last time* mean *the last time someone did something*?

In the second sentence, for example, does it mean *The last time we had a class/we discussed/we studied physics, we talked about the three forms of water*?

Comment: Both sentences work both with and without the "the".

Comment: But "This is the last time I am going to buy theatre tickets for you." (I won't do it again.)

Comment: And yes: "Last time we talked about the three forms of water" means "The last time we had a class/discussion..."